# Проверка переменной из базы данных MS и, если проверка прошла, вывод строки в dataGridView

Tags: c#, база-данных, oledb

Есть переменная int ID_search, которую необходимо сравнить с всеми переменными ID в базе данных Data_Base.accdb в таблице details. Если ID соответствует, то должен произойти вывод всей строки details в dataGridView1

Сделать надо через пространство имён System.Data.OleDb
В интернете уже час роюсь не могу понять как сравнивать поочерёдно с каждой переменной ID из базы данных

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну тут как бы как то так

```
select * from details where ID_search == id;
```

в ответ придет коллекция и уже с ней работать

Comment: В тегах C# и oledb.